# How to use a crate in another project so it won't compile again?

Tags: rust

I want to use my hellow_crate inside my hello_project so that the crate will not be recompiled.

This is my crate structure:

```
hellow_crate
|__src
|  |__lib.rs
|__Cargo.lock
|__Cargo.toml
```

This is my crate's `Cargo.toml` file:

```
[package]
name = "hellow_new"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["John <john@123gmail.com>"]
[dependencies]
```

This is my project structure:

```
hello_project
|  |__main.rs
|__Cargo.lock
|__Cargo.toml
```

This is my project's `Cargo.toml` file:

```
[package]
name = "hello_project"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["John <john@123gmail.com>"]
[dependencies]
```

Comment: What have you tried? Perhaps [reading the documentation would be of use to you?](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-path-dependencies)

Comment: Thanks @Simon , I have used that path = ['path/to/lib'], but the thing is, It is my own local repo so If add this as a dependency so problem with that is I have to copy manually whole code with my co-workers also. And I don't want to create github link for every crate. Is there anything like I can add my files in the current project, and It will compile only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible solutions here.

### Add a dependency to your crate as a relative path:

Assuming the project structure is the following:

```
project
|__hellow_crate
|__hello_project
```

Then you can alter hellow_project's Cargo.toml file to look like this:

```
[package]
name = "hello_project"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["John <john@123gmail.com>"]
[dependencies]
hellow_crate = { path = "../hellow_crate" }
```

### Use a workspace:

If *hellow_crate* is only used by *hello_project* and won't be used as a dependency for another independent project, it makes sense to include it as part of a workspace.

In that case, the directory structure becomes the following:

```
hello_project
|__hellow_crate
|  |__src
|  |  |__lib.rs
|  |__Cargo.toml
|  |__Cargo.lock
|__src
|  |__main.rs
|__Cargo.lock
|__Cargo.toml
```

And alter hello_project's Cargo.toml file to look like this:

```
[package]
name = "hello_project"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["John <john@123gmail.com>"]

[workspace]
members = [ "hellow_crate" ]

[dependencies]
hellow_crate = { path = "hellow_crate" }
```

This has the advantage of making cargo compile all code in a single target directory, and allows you to run all tests of the project and the crate with `cargo test --all`.